# Inheritance in C# - override and virtual

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual

I'm new to C# override and virtual. In the following example I want to call Callee method in B class from Caller method in A class. B inherits A. Any thoughts?

```
namespace Blah
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            a.Caller();
        }
    }

    class A
    {
        public void Caller()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In Caller");
            Callee(); // How to make this call B:Callee() and make it print "in B"
        }

        public virtual void Callee()
        {
            Console.Write("In A");
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public override void Callee()
        {
            Console.Write("In B");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call the `Callee` method inside class `B`, you have first to create an instance of this class and then call this method:

```
var b = new B();
B.Callee();
```

If that is you are looking for (despite it does not make sense from a practical prespective), you should place the above two lines inside the method `Caller` in class `A`.

Usually we define a base class and if we think that a method in the class we define can be re-implemented from classes that would be derived from our class, we mark the method as virtual. When we derive a class from our base class and we do not override the virtual method, then the method that has been defined in the base class is called. Whereas when we have overriden a virtual method defined in a base class, the method in the derived class is called.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have the baseclass `A` with a subclass `B` that overrides a method in `A`. This means that you create an alternative `A`, that can interact as an `A` but might have different behavior.

However, this does not mean that every instance of `A` suddenly starts to use this definition. In your example you create a hard instance of `A`, but as the overriding method is in `B` it will never be called.

Instead you should create an instance of `B`, which you can cast to an `A`. Allowing your code to treat it as an `A` object, even though its `B`.

In your example, the only thing you'll need to do is create an instance of `B` ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y43CW8)):

```
    A a = new B();
    a.Caller(); 
    // Prints:
    //   In Caller
    //   In B
```

The way this works is more or less the same as Java inheritance, only in C# you need to mark methods as `virtual` in order to override them.

---

However, if your intention was to change definition of `Callee` in `A` without having to create a `B` (so `new A().Caller()`would print out "In B"), you should rethink whatever you are trying to do. It is something completely different from virtual methods and in most situations something you should try to avoid.